# Reversing lines from a file Python 3

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, reverse

I am trying to make lines from a text file in Python 3 be reversed and written to an outfile. Currently, I am having issues with the last line of the infile not containing \n on the end of the line. I am getting a TypeError from this code.

```
def main():

    endofprogram = False
    try:
        inputfile = input("Enter name of input file: ")

        ifile = open(inputfile, "r", encoding="utf-8")

        outputfile = input("Enter name of output file: ")
        while os.path.isfile(outputfile):
            if True:
                outputfile = input("File Exists. Enter name again: ")        
        ofile = open(outputfile, "w")        


    except IOError:
        print("Error opening file - End of program")
        endofprogram = True

    #If there is not exception, start reading the input file

    if endofprogram == False:
        newline = "\n"
        for line in ifile:
            line = line.strip            
            line = line + "\n"            
            lines = ifile.readlines()

    lines.reverse()
    newlines= "".join(lines)
    print(newlines)     
    ifile.close()
    ofile.close()

main() # Call the main to execute the solution
```

Comment: What exactly is that ".reverse"? And wouldn't it be easier to just use reverse = lines[::-1]? Also last line of the file does not need to have new line character.

Comment: The .reverse reverses a list. I am in a computing 101 class and we have not learned [::1], so I don't feel comfortable using it because we have to be able to explain why our code works. The last line in this case does need a new line character, because it will later be the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this to make it work...

```
if endofprogram == False:         

    lines = ifile.readlines()
    linelist = []
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        line = line + "\n"

        linelist.append(line)


    linelist.reverse()

    newlines= "".join(linelist)
    ofile.write(newlines)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this with your specifications - assuming I understand correctly and that literally all you want to do is just reverse the order of every line - would just be to take advantage of the `reverse` method for the list in python. So, for any given line:

```
#define line here
line_list = list(line)
line_list.reverse()
reversed_line = ''.join(line_list)
```

Edit: based on your issue with the newline characters, here's a modification:

```
#define line here
line_list = list(line.replace('\n', ''))
line_list.reverse()
reversed_line = ''.join(line_list) + '\n'
```

Comment: I do this later, but the problem is the last line in the file does not have "\n", so when I reverse the files, the new first line and second line are combined.

Comment: @KiraShelton Okay, I've made a modification to the code to make sure that there's always only one \n character in any given line, and it's at the end.